# Couldn't show image to PDF report from firebase storage by link available on FirebaseFirestore

Tags: flutter, firebase, pdf, firebase-storage

I was facing an issue in image uploading to firebase storage and I have its link available in my firestore.
I want to show this image to my pdf report.
What my pseudocode is:

1. Get the image link.
2. Download it and turn it into bytes.
3. Show it onto pdf report.
   This is my code:

```
var response;
var imageData;
try {
  response = await http.get(Uri.parse(imageUrl!));
  if (response.statusCode == 200) { // Check for successful response
    imageData = response.bodyBytes;
  } else {
    print('Error fetching image: ${response.statusCode}');
  }
} catch (e) {
  print('Error: $e');
}
```

This is where I'm showing the image in report:

```
pw.Align(
  alignment: pw.Alignment.bottomLeft,
  child: pw.Image(
    pw.MemoryImage(imageData),
    width: 100,
    height: 80,
  ),
),
```

This is the error I'm facing:

> Error: ClientException: XMLHttpRequest error., uri=https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/dmlive-1128c.appspot.com/o/1704722630561?alt=media&token=4b4de6d3-0c4e-411f-9f2c-28d7c30cdde2

These are my storage rules on firebase:

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

I confirmed that user trying to download is authenticated, but they can't access the file.

Comment: I simulated your code and it works perfectly fine : https://pastebin.com/BA1m0wGp, What i'm thinking is maybe you have internet connection issue

Comment: Is there more to the error than what you provided?  It doesn't tell us anything other than that an error occurred.  Usually you would get more details as to the specifics of the error (network, SSL/certificate, or something like that).